# After how many days can I answer my own question?

Tags: support, self-answer

I asked a question on stackoverflow, with no answer so far (3 weeks). In the meanwhile I found a good answer for my own question but I'm not able to post this answer to my own question. Do I have to wait some more days until I can post an answer? There is not post form.

This is my question: [.NET Automation ControlType.Document: how to manipulate text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6708022/net-automation-controltype-document-how-to-manipulate-text)

[image]

Comment: You should be able to post it - what exact error message you get?

Comment: There is no form at all to post an answer!

Comment: Uh... You have to click the "Answer Your Question" button. The form isn't shown by default on your own questions.

Comment: @Cody Gray: Aaaaah! Thanks! I didn't saw it! Was focused on my form!

Comment: Still the question: after how many days?

Comment: None. You can answer your own question immediately. Just click the button. It might prompt you with "are you sure" or something, but you definitely can answer your own question as soon as you post it.

Comment: If something's going wrong, check that you don't have a proxy or firewall or antivirus or something interfering with your ability to do so. (See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90284/answering-my-own-question-is-not-working) for a related case.)

Comment: that update should really be an answer.. again by you ;)

Answer (score 10):

You can answer your own question immediately. The answer box isn't shown initially on your own question, but you can press the `Answer Your Question` button.

There is a [restriction for new users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86185/minimum-reputation-for-answering-your-own-question-should-be-higher-than-what-is/86186#86186): if you have less than 100 rep, you must wait 8 hours to be able to post an answer to your own question. This is because new users often misuse answers to reply to answers or comments, when they should have used a comment instead.

You won't be able to accept your own answer until 48 hours after you posted the question.

Answer (score 4):

1. First I missed the <kbd>Answer Your Question</kbd> button.
2. Second I'm able to **answer immediately**.
3. And if something still does not work check this: [Answering my own question is not working](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90284/answering-my-own-question-is-not-working)

Thanks [Cody Gray](https://stackoverflow.com/users/366904/)!

Comment: you can answer immediately because you have > 100 rep